# Unable to activate AdSense

Tags: angular, adsense, activation

I wanted to add some ads to a small website I built. It's just a small simple angular site, not wordpress or something else. Every time I click "Get started with AdSense for Content" on the AdSense page I get the following message:

`We apologize for the inconvenience, but we are unable to process your request at this time. Our engineers have been notified of this problem and will work to resolve it.`

This hasn't changed in the days days no matter what I try. Googling this error I found several answers, but none helped. I tried different browsers, cleared all site data and even tried with several different devices.

I just don't seem to be getting out more information than that. Also following some guidelines in adding AdSense to a page dosn't work, due to not being able to add my site because I don't have the appropriate settings option.

The strange thing is that I see all my data from my AdMob account, which still works without any problems.

Any Ideas what could be wrong or how I could get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

It can also happen on the "Allow & block ads" pages within the Adsense area. For me the solution was to disable Adblock on google.com domain (and/or any other ad-blocking extensions in your web browser).